# Parallel Offset of a Polygon Edge with Shapely

Tags: python, buffer, shapely, offset

I need to offset edges of a polygon by different amounts.

[`buffer()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer) will parallel-offset all the edges by the same amount, and each in its edge-normal direction (and in both directions if applied to a `LineString`).

[`parallel_offset()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.parallel_offset) will offset a whole LineString by the same amount, but that means that if given only some edges of a polygon, the result is disconnected from the other neighboring polygon edges which were not offset. It will take care of the corners/joints only within the LineString and not on the sides.

Is there a way to nicely offset polygon edges with different amounts while still getting nice correct corners?